# confusion in David Burton number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From elementary number theory by  David Burton books

Theorem $2.4$: Let $a$ and $b$ be integers, not both zero. Then $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime
if and only if there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $1 = ax + by.$

I think this theorem is not true:  take $a=2, b=3 , x= 1, y=2$;

then $1 \neq 2.1 + 3.2= 2+6=8$ but here gcd$( 2,3)=1$.

My confusion is that  Is this theorem is true/false ?

Comment: Did you think that the theorem says $1=ax+by$ for all $x$ and $y$?  That's not true, and that's not what the theorem says

Comment: i was thinking for all $x$ and $y$ @J.W.Tanner..that mean universally is not true

Comment: saying "there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that..."  is not the same as saying "for all integers $x$ and $y$ we have..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem is true.

Given $a=2$ and $b=3$, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ (such as $-1$ and $1$, respectively)

such that $ax+by=1$.